# How to eliminate race condition during db transaction - read row count from db, calculate input, then insert value to db?

Tags: asp.net, race-condition, llblgenpro

Scenario: 
A save function first reads the total number of rows from a table in the db.
Based on the number of rows, a unique input value is calculated. This value is included in the row that is then inserted into the same table.

Problem:
Two instances of the same object executes the save function at the same time. Here "same time" is the amount of time that it takes the application to read from and insert a row into the db. So, for example,

- User A clicks save button >> Reads that there are 3 rows in the table >> Calculates f(3) as a unique input value for the new row >> Prepares the new row to insert into the table ...
- User B clicks save button >> (since User A has not inserted the new row) Reads that there are 3 rows in the table >> Calculates f(3) which is NOT a unique value (ERROR!) >> ...

How do I rectify this situation? I am not able to alter the db transaction logic since an abstracted ORM layer is being used unfortunately. I have full control over the code however. Any suggestion will be very helpful.

I have anready tried putting a lock() around the save function, but its not helping somehow.

Comment: What's the purpose of the unique calculation?

Comment: How is the row count retrieved? Is it via a stored procedure call, or via your ORM? Maybe your ORM layer is caching the row count from user A? That could possibly explain why the lock isn't working.

Comment: @mgnoonan The unique calculation is for creating an identifier for the given record. This identifier specification needs to be sequencial as per the requirement.

Comment: @KazR The row count is retrieved via the ORM. I will check on the caching. If that were the case, what would your approach be for the solution? I will look into it to see if the ORM provides any functional way to alleaviate the problem.

Comment: Can you use a SEQUENCE or IDENTIFIER rather than doing a ROWCOUNT?

Comment: @mgnoonan Thank you for the advice. I will look into SEQUENCE and IDENTIFIER as alternatives. Given the structure of the application, however, using a different way of calculating the identifier for the record could be problematic in terms of requirements. If there is a way to add checks or change the order of steps described above to get around the race-condition, that would be ideal. Thank you again!

Comment: what ORM are you using? Is it an in-house one, or a commercial/open source implementation?

Comment: @KazR We are using the LLBLGen Pro. I changed the code to use the entity object's getRowCount() method - as opposed to getting the total count via sql statement. This seems to have made the first step of the process faster and reduced the probability of the race-condition. But I am still looking for a solution at a logical level, so that the race-condition is completely eliminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up leveraging the DB generated ID (auto-increment) to do my calculations. Since, rowcount and ID were out of sync, adjusted the new custom id by adding an integer to the new sequence to match the old sequence.